# Calculate percentage between two numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

I have two numbers which summed up are considered to be $100\%$.

The first number $n_1$ should decide the percentage amount.

For e.g.,

$$n_1 = 5$$

$$n_2 = 15$$

so the percentage in this case would be $25\%$.

How do I calculate this? :) I mean how do I get the formula?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we want $\dfrac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}$. I don't really have much else to say about it. If you want it in %, multiply by 100. Otherwise, it's a decimal between 0 and 1.